# how can i add a variable from a function to global variable?

Tags: python, function

i want the score() function to work as to store p_score in player_score and vice versa

```
import random
player_cards=[]
computer_cards=[]
player_score=0
computer_score=0
def deal_cards():
    cards=[11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]
    return random.choice(cards)

def hand_cards():
    player_cards.append(deal_cards())
    computer_cards.append(deal_cards())

def first_gmae():
    for i in range(2):
        hand_cards()
    print(f"Player Cards : {player_cards}")
    print(f"Computer Cards : X ,{computer_cards[random.randint(0,1)]}")

def score(p_score,c_score):
    for i in player_cards:
        p_score+=i
    for j in computer_cards:
        c_score+=j
first_gmae()
score(p_score=player_score,c_score=computer_score)
print(player_score)
```

but the actual value returns 0 when i run the code... am i doing something stupid?

Comment: Changing `p_score` and `c_score` within a function won't affect the values of `player_score` and `computer_score` outside it.

Comment: modify the global variables player_score and computer_score directly. Right now you are modifying parameters

Comment: Also: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can return the newly calculated values and put them back in the variables they came from:

```py
def score(p_score,c_score):
    for i in player_cards:
        p_score += i
    for j in computer_cards:
        c_score += j
    return p_score,c_score

first_gmae()
player_score,computer_score = score(p_score=player_score,c_score=computer_score)
print(player_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `p_score` and `c_score` within a function won't affect the values of `player_score` and `computer_score` outside it.

I took the liberty of slightly simplifying your code here to make it easier to understand (and fixed a bug where your deck of cards wasn't actually depleting):

```
import random

deck = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
player_cards = []
computer_cards = []

def deal_card():
    # Choose a card from the deck, remove it from the deck
    # and return its value.
    card = random.choice(deck)
    deck.remove(card)
    return card

# Deal two cards to each player.
for i in range(2):
    player_cards.append(deal_card())
    computer_cards.append(deal_card())

# Compute the sum of their values (which is the score of the hand)
player_score = sum(player_cards)
computer_score = sum(computer_cards)

print(f"Player Cards   : {player_cards}")
print(f"Computer Cards : {computer_cards}")
print(f"Remaining deck : {deck}")
print(f"Player Score   : {player_score}")
print(f"Computer Score : {computer_score}")
```